# clearing out dojox/mobile/Accordion contained objects

Tags: dojo

I'm trying to destroy descendants of Accordion, that is I have 4 Content Panes within an Accrdion and then when I get new data I want to repopulate the accordion with that data(eg 5 ContentPanes) but the issue is that Once I call destroyDescendants on the accordion the content panes still reside within as dijit__Contained objects left from previous data:

```
<div class="mblAccordionTitle mblAccordionHasIcon mblAccordionTitleSelected" id="dijit__Contained_0" widgetid="dijit__Contained_0" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">
    <a class="mblAccordionTitleAnchor" role="presentation">
        <div class="mblAccordionIconParent mblAccordionIconParent2">
            <div class="mblSpriteIconParent" style="position: relative; width: 32px; height: 32px;">
                <img alt="" src="images/i.png" class="mblSpriteIcon" style="position: absolute; clip: rect(0px 32px 32px 0px    ); top: 0px; left: 0px;">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mblAccordionIconParent mblAccordionIconParent1">
            <div class="mblSpriteIconParent" style="position: relative; width: 32px; height: 32px;">
                <img alt="" src="images/i.png" class="mblSpriteIcon" style="position: absolute; clip: rect(0px 64px 32px     32px); top: 0px; left: -32px;">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mblAccordionTitleTextBox" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-controls="widget/PersonContainerContentPane" aria    -selected="true" aria-posinset="1" aria-setsize="4">
            <span class="mblAccordionTitleLabel">John Smith
            </span>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Also the contained object is not a child of accordion...

Is there any way to get rid of this when I call destroyDescendants on accordion?

Answer (score 0):

That solved my problem:

```
for (var i = this.accordion.containerNode.childNodes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    registry.byId(this.accordion.containerNode.childNodes[i].id).destroyRecursive(false);
};
```

Don't know why destroyDescendants didn't clean up leftover html.